# Automatic sprite animation with Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class representing my character in Cocos2d. 
I've exported the spritesheet + .plist file.

The character has multiple animations.

The frames are simply called **"Character_1.png"**.
Up to four. This is the basic walking animation.

In many sprite animation tutorials I found this sample code, which loops though the sprite frame cache and just adds it to an array so you can animate it:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    [animationFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Character_%d.png", i]]];
}
```

However, because most of my sprites will be animated just like this, I'd like to delegate this to an super class.

I thought about calling it something like

```
spriteWithAnimations:(NSArray *)animationNames
```

and then I'd look though them, just like in the example above.

So as a parameter in the array I'd get a string `@"Character_%d"`, I'd make a while loop and check if the file exists, and while so, I'd add it to the array.

The only problem is, that I cannot check if a frame **"Character_05.png"** exists, because `CCSpriteFrameCache` has no such method.

How is this usually solved?

Comment: check the CCAnimation extension class in Kobold2D www.kobold2d.com, it already does what you plan on doing

Comment: Sorry I have already defined in the concept that I'm using Cocos2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CCSpriteFrameCache returns nil for a given frame name you know it doesn't exist. Not elegant but it works.

Comment: I think it crashes, rather than returning a `nil` value.

Comment: Ok I tested it and it actually does work, but it still prints out an error... Isn't there any other way to do this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. You were right, the log is just a debugging log, it won't log anything when deployed. Thanks for your help!